# preg_match_all() - Use text within brackets, but don't show the whitespaces

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I want to create an array from a string that contains brackets like {! !}. However the whitespaces at the beginning and at the end of the encapsulated string should not be displayed.

```
$string = "{! This should be in the output !} this should not be in the output {!show_in_output!} don't show {!   show   !}";
preg_match_all("/{!(.*)!}/Us", $string , $output);
```

The resulting array looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => {! This should be in the output !}
            [1] => {!show_in_output!}
            [2] => {!   show   !}
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  This should be in the output 
            [1] => show_in_output
            [2] =>    show   
        )

)
```

But it should look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
...
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => This should be in the output 
            [1] => show_in_output
            [2] => show   
        )

)
```

Is there a way to achieve this with a modified regex?
Thank you!

Comment: Why modify a regex when you can just trim post-regex?

Comment: And yes, it can be modified.

Comment: Of course you can trim it post-regex, but I think that's not the right way to use regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(.*)` in the middle of `/{!(.*)!}/` matches any characters between your `{!` and `!}`. If you want to NOT capture spaces before and after that, you have to match whitespace and not include the whitespace in your group, so in your case:  `/{!\s*(.*?)\s*!}/`.  The `?` says to make a minimal match of the `.*` so that it doesn't include the whitespace that you want matched by the second `\s*`.

Comment: You're very welcome.  Please click the grey check mark so it shows that you've accepted the answer.

Comment: I just try to understand it completely now. Why is `.*` more greedy than the `\s*`? Because this version, where I make `\s*` more greedy, works too: `/{!\s*?(.*)\s*!}/U`